# General question about interpolation and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, interpolation

I have a pooled data with two-monthly frequency. lets say response variable is y. I want monthly time series for y. Can someone please share link to methods through which I can better predict the monthly values of y using some machine learning or statistical model that takes into account the relation of y with all the other variables lets say (a,b,c and d) in the dataset and then gives an output that is not just dependent on time but also on the input that I provide for a,b, c and d in the given period.

Please refer to the table below where y is my response variable and (a,b,c) are character variables that are variable across respondents and d is the time fixed variable (e.g inflation level at time t). In total I have two-monthly data from January 2012 till July 2022. That makes it 144 months but since survey is conducted every two months I have survey data for every second month. I want to predict the monthly data from this.

lets say we have a data in the following table:

| Time | y | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 23 | 09 | 12 | 4 |
| 1 | 65 | 89 | 45 | 10 | 4 |
| 1 | 24 | 32 | 12 | 12 | 4 |
| 1 | 25 | 78 | 09 | 45 | 4 |
| 1 | 87 | 39 | 65 | 56 | 4 |
| 1 | 45 | 36 | 36 | 26 | 4 |
| 2 | - | 23 | 75 | 63 | 6 |
| 2 | - | 12 | 16 | 36 | 6 |
| 2 | - | 23 | 48 | 16 | 6 |
| 2 | - | 89 | 45 | 18 | 6 |
| 2 | - | 73 | 09 | 75 | 6 |
| 2 | - | 23 | 65 | 64 | 6 |
| 3 | 56 | 36 | 72 | 81 | 9 |
| 3 | 19 | 92 | 36 | 98 | 9 |
| 3 | 18 | 43 | 24 | 42 | 9 |
| 3 | 45 | 51 | 42 | 52 | 9 |
| 3 | 56 | 15 | 95 | 52 | 9 |
| 3 | 23 | 56 | 98 | 52 | 9 |
| 4 | - | 36 | 72 | 52 | 3 |
| 4 | - | 91 | 36 | 41 | 3 |
| 4 | - | 43 | 24 | 31 | 3 |
| 4 | - | 51 | 43 | 54 | 3 |
| 4 | - | 36 | 65 | 64 | 3 |
| 4 | - | 92 | 64 | 64 | 3 |
| 4 | - | 43 | 56 | 76 | 3 |

Comment: There's infinite ways you could do this. You need to give us many more details with context to get concrete (useful) advice.

Comment: can you please name a few methods  that uses all the series to predict values of y. I am not looking for interpolation methods that are univariate. Or better if you can refer me some book or research article that looks into these methods